# Intersection of a set that contains the floor function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to solve the next question:

For all $m\in I=(0,1)$ there is a subset $A_m \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ that $A_{m} = \{ a\in \mathbb{R} : a-\lfloor a \rfloor < m \} $. Find $\bigcap\limits_{m\in I} A_{m}$

So I think that the solution is $\bigcap\limits_{m\in I} A_m=\mathbb{Z}$, and I tried to prove it like this:

let $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ then $-x\leq-\lfloor x\rfloor<1-x$.

Therefore $0=-x+x\leq x-\lfloor x\rfloor<x+1-x=1$, so for every $m\in I, x\in A_{m} $

and then $x\in\bigcap\limits_{m\in I} A_{m}$, so $\mathbb{Z}\subseteq \bigcap\limits_{m\in I} A_{m}$.

Now I need to prove that $\bigcap\limits_{m\in I} A_{m} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, but how?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you wanted to see  $\bigcap_{m\in I}$ or $\bigcap\limits_{m\in I},$ but you repeatedly coded it as \underset{m\in I}{\bigcap} rather than as either \bigcap_{m\in I} or \bigcap\limits_{m\in I}. That seems to set a sub-optimal example for others who may see it and try to base their MathJax coding on it, so I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $a-\lfloor a \rfloor \ge 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, with equality if and only if $a \in \mathbb{Z}$. (In fact, this observation already proves that $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \bigcap_{m \in I} A_m$, without having to chase inequalities like you did.)

To see that $\bigcap_{m \in I} A_m \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$, consider $a \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ and let $m=a-\lfloor a \rfloor.$ Then $m \in (0,1),$ since $a \not \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Is $a \in A_m$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\notin\mathbb Z.$ Then $x-\lfloor x\rfloor>0.$ Let $m = (x-\lfloor x \rfloor)/2.$ Then $x\notin A_m,$ so $x$ is not in the intersection.